# How to retrieve a MAX() from a query while keeping the query result?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count, max

I want to make a simple bar chart of some statistics in my database. More specifically: it's a family tree, and I want to show the birth frequency per month. I managed to create the SQL query to get a list of the months with their respective numbers of births. Now I want to add a coloured bar, where the highest number is 100% width, and the others are proportional.

To calculate the percentage, I need to get the largest number from the query result. I do not, however, need to display that. I only need the number to use it to calculate the width of the bar.

I have tried different solutions with MAX(), but these were all set to display only the maximum value of the COUNT(). As mentioned, I want to display the full result, and only need the MAX() internally for calculations. I do not need to display it.

It is easy to retrieve the number by doing a SELECT() query ordering by the COUNT() and limiting to the first result. As the needed MAX() result is only one number, I cannot do a UNION with the other SELECT query that gets me the numbers per month.
Second problem is that the results to be displayed are not ordered by COUNT(), obviously, but by month. So at this time the MAX() number would be the third result, though that can change when I add to my database.

```
<?php

require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
mysqli_select_db($connection, DB_NAME);

$query = "SELECT
    MONTHNAME(birthdatetr) AS Month_of_Birth,
    MONTH(birthdatetr) AS number_of_month_of_birth,
    COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM
    tng_people
WHERE
    MONTH(birthdatetr) > 0
GROUP BY
    number_of_month_of_birth
ORDER BY
    number_of_month_of_birth";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$barwidth = floor($Total / $birthmax * 100);
?>

<?php foreach ($result as $row){    
echo "{$row['Month_of_Birth']} ({$row['Total']})
<td class=\"bar-holder\"><div style=\"width:{$barwidth}%;\" class=\"bar rightround\"></div></td>";
}
    ?>
```

This is the code I have to display my list of months. I have named the max-variable "birthmax", I just don't know how to assign a value to it. The value should be the largest result of the "Total".
"Barwidth" is the calculated size of the coloured bar I want to display. With the code as is, so lacking a value for birthmax, the bars, months and numbers are displayed, but the bar is at full width, saying that the value assigned to barwidth is not a number (NAN).

Comment: Your query isn't even valid, see [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

Comment: The query itself works perfectly, in both phpMyAdmin as live on my website... It displays the results just as I need, anyway. Why wouldn't it be valid? The only thing I can see is that I should rather order by MONTH(birthdaretr) but this works as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using MYSQL 8.0 and above, you can use `WITH` to create two tables, the table you already made and a table that only has the max value. Then cross join the two tables to add the max value to each row.

You can also select Total / max_total to get a percentage between 0 and 1.

```sql
WITH query_data AS (
    SELECT
        MONTHNAME(birthdatetr) AS Month_of_Birth,
        MONTH(birthdatetr) AS number_of_month_of_birth,
        COUNT(*) AS Total
    FROM
        tng_people
    WHERE
        MONTH(birthdatetr) > 0
    GROUP BY
        number_of_month_of_birth
),
max_count AS (
    SELECT MAX(Total) AS max_total FROM query_data
)
SELECT query_data.*, max_count.max_total
FROM query_data CROSS JOIN max_count
ORDER BY
        query_data.number_of_month_of_birth
```

For mysql < 8.0 you can join the two tables like this:

```sql
SELECT query_data.*, max_count.max_total
FROM (
    SELECT
        MONTHNAME(birthdatetr) AS Month_of_Birth,
        MONTH(birthdatetr) AS number_of_month_of_birth,
        COUNT(*) AS Total
    FROM
        tng_people
    WHERE
        MONTH(birthdatetr) > 0
    GROUP BY
        number_of_month_of_birth
) query_data
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(tmp_max.Total) AS max_total FROM
    (
        SELECT
            MONTHNAME(birthdatetr) AS Month_of_Birth,
            MONTH(birthdatetr) AS number_of_month_of_birth,
            COUNT(*) AS Total
        FROM
            tng_people
        WHERE
            MONTH(birthdatetr) > 0
        GROUP BY
            number_of_month_of_birth
    ) tmp_max
) max_count
ORDER BY
    query_data.number_of_month_of_birth
```

Comment: The second option for php <v8.0 also gives a "non numeric result"... Assuming that the $ representing the MAX value is max_total. I'll have another look at it tomorrow morning with a fresh head, so I can better understand what the code does exactly. Looks interesting.

Comment: FYI I tried your query in phpMyAdmin, and there it works perfectly... Just like the other solution provided by Moneer. I don't know why my code doesn't recognise the $barwidth as a number...

Comment: In your question, you had this line `$barwidth = floor($Total / $birthmax * 100);` before the for loop. $Total and $birthmax are undefined. If you move it inside the for loop and change it to `$barwidth = floor($row['Total'] /$row['max_total'] * 100);` it should work

Comment: *"My provider only supports MYSQL up to 7.02.17 unfortunately"* MySQL 7 did i mis something? @TomHuygens MySQL 6 and 7 never existed, MySQL went from MySQL 5.7  directly to MySQL 8.. That version `7.02.17` is most likely your PHP version?

Comment: @RaymondNijland oops.... yes, that's my php version... Bear with me, I'm a beginner.

Comment: @HassanSaleh of course, silly me... It works perfectly now! Thanks for you patience and your help!

Answer (score 0):

One soulution is a subquery, that get's the highest count.

```
SELECT monthname(birthdatetr) month_of_birth,
       month(birthdatetr) number_of_month_of_birth,
       count(*) total,
       (SELECT count(*)
               FROM tng_people
               WHERE month(birthdatetr) > 0
               GROUP BY month(birthdatetr)
               ORDER BY count(*) DESC
               LIMIT 1) overall_total
       FROM tng_people
       WHERE month(birthdatetr) > 0
       GROUP BY month(birthdatetr)
       ORDER BY month(birthdatetr);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this breaks the code. Nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

i do not know if i got the idea right but i believe you can use subquery

```
  SELECT
        MONTHNAME(birthdatetr) AS Month_of_Birth,
        MONTH(birthdatetr) AS number_of_month_of_birth,
        COUNT(*) AS Total,
(select count(*) FROM tng_people
               WHERE month(birthdatetr) > 0
               GROUP BY month(birthdatetr)
               ORDER BY count(*) DESC
               limit 1) as birthmax
    FROM
        tng_people
    WHERE
        MONTH(birthdatetr) > 0
    GROUP BY
        number_of_month_of_birth
    ORDER BY
        number_of_month_of_birth
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but as the other answer, it unfortunately returns no results at all. It breaks the complete php.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I forgot a "," somewhere. It now displays the same as before, saying that the birthmax is not a number...
When I isolate the subquery in MySQL, it does give a number.

Comment: what do you get if you run the query in mysql (the complete query)

Comment: When executing the query in phpMyAdmin, it gives what I'm looking for. The full table, numbers per month, with an added column with the maximum number (same for each row).
So the problem probably is somewhere with WordPress handling the code...

Thanks for helping out, at least I know this solution works in a normal world!

Comment: try using var_dump($result) ; die() to see what values are you getting and also change width:{$barwidth} to $row[barwidth']